# Visual Studio 2010 build outputs extra files in 'bin' root

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Recently, I changed a Visual Studio solution that contains about 140 projects to output all the library project's output files to the same `bin` folder in the solutions root directory.

After changing all the project's output directories and doing a re-build, I noticed some projects output both in the correct `bin\\{platform}\\{configuration}\lib\` folder but also in the `bin\` folder. The files appear to be the exact same. Only the DLL and [PDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) files go into the `bin` folder, the configuration file and XML documentation file do not.  If I do a clean, the files in the `bin` folder do not get deleted. I can build the projects one at a time and some do this, some don't. If I build using [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) from the command line this does not happen.

Is this expected/normal? I built with the MSBuild output set to diagnostics but there is no mention of the `bin\` folder alone, all mentions of the `bin` folder include the correct platform, configuration etc..

Comment: Try setting all of the OutDir, LibPath, ImagePath, IntDir and OutputPath property as they're used by various systems. If this doesn't work, you can always use the trick of creating a folder where the rogue file would be created, and see if MSBuild gives a useful error message - e.g. if it would create c:\foo\bar.txt then create a folder in c:\foo called 'bar.txt'. This will force MSBuild to fail, possibly with a useful error message!

Comment: @Mike - Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll need to look into changing the env variables some more since i'm not too familiar with those.  I created a folder called "foo.dll" and it did prevent both the dll and pdb files from being created in the bin root, but unfortunately no errors from msbuild.  The build output is practically identical to when the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I've got the same behaviour on a project in VS2010. I can't work out why this /Bin folder is being created. I've double/triple checked all the output paths I know of!

Comment: Looking at this, if I load each project individual, this never happens. The behaviour **only** occurs when a project references another project.

Comment: Same behaviour too, if I set this new 'solution-root\Bin' folder to ReadOnly, the files cannot be written into this location, but even with the MSBUILD output set to diagnostic verbosity, there is no apparent difference. 

My initial guess is, this won't happen if MSBuild is invoked from the command line, and is a bug in how Visual Studio is working out the build dependancies / order.

It would be interesting to see if that happens via the command line, and if it happens when MSBuild parses the .sln into a Build file. I'll  see what I can do tomorrow.

Comment: Doesn't happen if the project is build via the command line.

Comment: Anyone know if this was reported to MS as a bug ? or find a work around that doesn't involve MSBuild from the command line ?